# C compiler error - initializer not constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a function used to create a new `GQueue`

```
GQueue* newGQueue(int n_ele, int ele_size)
{
    GQueue* q = (GQueue*) malloc(sizeof(GQueue));
    if(!q) return NULL;

    q->ptr = malloc(n_ele * ele_size);
    if(!(q->ptr))
    {
        free(q);
        return NULL;
    }

    q->in = q->out = q->count = 0;
    q->size = n_ele; q->ele_size = ele_size;

    return q;
}
```

I use it like this:

`volatile GQueue * kbdQueue = newGQueue(10, 1);`

However, the following compilation error occurs at this line:

`Error: initializer element not constant`

Why does this happen? 10 and 1 are obviously constants which shouldn't bother `malloc`, etc in pre `c99` C code.

Only flag is `-Wall`.

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's saying that `newGQueue()` is not a constant. A constant is determined at compile time, while a call to a function can't happen until run time.

Comment: Yeah, I gave it some thought and it makes sense. Only works on C99 then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only initialize global variables at their declaration with a constant value, which `newGQueue` is not.

This is because all global variables must be initialized before a program can begin execution. The compiler takes any constant values assigned to globals at their declaration and uses that value in the program's [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) which is loaded directly into memory by the [OS loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)) when the program is run.

Just initialize your kbdQueue at declaration to NULL and initialize it to a value in main or other startup function.

```
volatile GQueue * kbdQueue = NULL;

int main() {
    kbdQueue = newGQueue(10,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the arguments for newGQueue, is for using the newGQueue return value to initialize kbdQueue. That's executable code, and in C all initializers have to be known at compile time.
This is a problem in C only; C++ would accept it without problems.

If you break apart the declaration and initialization it should work OK.

```
volatile GQueue * kbdQueue;
kbdQueue = newGQueue(10, 1);
```

Comment: To my knowledge that isn't accepted in any C "flavor", only in C++. But nowadays I do little good-old C code, so I can't answer for sure. I know, though, that C99 relaxed some old C restrictions, making it a bit more C++-like.