# Error 1 error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C compiler error - initializer not constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462868/c-compiler-error-initializer-not-constant)
>   [Definition of global variables using a non constant initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785250/definition-of-global-variables-using-a-non-constant-initializer)

I have 2 variables defined globally given below and I get the C2099 error. I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Here are the variables:

```
const char* key = "AZFFProgramFiles";
const char* val = getenv(key);
```

Comment: Although the code would be OK in C++, using a function to initialize a variable at global scope is not allowed in C.

Answer (score 0):

since `val` is declared at static file level, its value must be known to the compiler at compile time. This is not the case, since you initialize it by calling `getenv(key)`. This because global values are placed in a special storage area of the binary file which is created at compile time.

Comment: Nothing to do with the `const` qualifier; you simply can't use a function call to initialize a global variable in C (unlike C++).

Comment: Also, note that `val` **is not `const` qualified**. The type it points to is `const`-qualified. And such pointers are perfectly capable of pointing to objects which are not `const` qualified.

Comment: thanks muchh.. helped a lot..u guys rock!!! :)